# I have nodes,edges, and weights. How can i draw the network from nodes,edges,weight info in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have made the Network as following:

```
p <- 100 # Number of nodes (genes) in the network.
n <- 100 # Number of samples to generate.
network <- random_network(p) # Create a random network of size p.
network <- gen_partial_correlations(network) # Generate weights.
df_ref <- SeqNet::reference$rnaseq  # The reference dataset
g <-network
```

Now from g, i can extract the nodes and edges as a list likewise:

```
nodeslist<- list(g$modules[[1]]$nodes)
edgeslist<- list(g$modules[[1]]$edges)
```

note: nodeslist and edgeslist contains information as following:
edgeslist:

```
            weight
[1,] 1 49 0.13920793
[2,] 2 19 -0.16105155
[3,] 2 29 -0.11896011
[4,] 2 49 0.10574541
[5,] 3 29 -0.13120939
[6,] 3 49 0.17390062
[7,] 4 10 -0.10381197
[8,] 5 33 -0.13458892
[9,] 6 49 0.17523747
[10,] 7 19 0.18709664
[11,] 8 49 -0.10200550
[12,] 9 10 -0.16075495
[13,] 9 49 0.12597721
[14,] 10 11 0.12419045
[15,] 10 18 0.16554176
[16,] 10 23 0.12257816
[17,] 10 24 0.17552470
[18,] 10 25 -0.18485569
[19,] 10 28 -0.18851376
[20,] 10 29 -0.17173121
[21,] 10 32 0.14237557
[22,] 10 33 -0.15823895
[23,] 10 34 0.12432978
[24,] 10 35 -0.16700940
[25,] 10 37 0.17640358
[26,] 10 43 -0.10804470
[27,] 10 44 0.16079198
[28,] 10 45 -0.13074089
[29,] 10 47 -0.14941716
[30,] 10 48 0.17069436
[31,] 10 49 -0.14465740
[32,] 10 50 -0.16713456
[33,] 10 51 -0.12124140
[34,] 10 53 0.09832430
[35,] 10 55 -0.16044640
[36,] 10 62 0.15869645
[37,] 10 63 0.11175158
[38,] 12 49 -0.19139133
[39,] 13 29 0.14681721
[40,] 13 49 0.13493487
[41,] 14 33 -0.13364581
[42,] 15 19 0.10663959
[43,] 15 49 -0.11776805
[44,] 16 49 -0.17496817
[45,] 17 49 0.13980787
[46,] 19 24 0.16020803
[47,] 19 25 -0.12007548
[48,] 19 26 0.13061010
[49,] 19 30 0.18347088
[50,] 19 32 0.17066294
[51,] 19 33 -0.16345597
[52,] 19 37 0.12446608
[53,] 19 46 0.13531279
[54,] 19 49 0.10353267
[55,] 19 52 -0.12596833
[56,] 19 63 0.11966468
[57,] 20 49 -0.13018907
[58,] 21 33 -0.10584546
[59,] 21 49 -0.16366432
[60,] 22 29 -0.12769928
[61,] 24 29 0.09683651
[62,] 24 49 -0.17398705
[63,] 25 30 -0.18163093
[64,] 25 34 0.13093457
[65,] 25 35 0.18703481
[66,] 25 41 0.11050505
[67,] 25 44 -0.09962966
[68,] 25 47 0.18286832
[69,] 26 29 0.14178880
[70,] 26 33 -0.10631235
[71,] 27 37 -0.14746540
[72,] 28 33 0.09948649
[73,] 29 30 0.13360557
[74,] 29 31 -0.16245800
[75,] 29 32 -0.16785796
[76,] 29 33 -0.15289176
[77,] 29 39 -0.17283268
[78,] 29 43 0.10077533
[79,] 29 49 -0.13001863
[80,] 29 50 -0.11811612
[81,] 29 51 -0.17453024
[82,] 29 53 -0.12620716
[83,] 29 59 -0.16878030
[84,] 29 63 0.11351594
[85,] 30 37 0.15382473
[86,] 30 49 0.18885891
[87,] 31 49 0.16179096
[88,] 32 49 0.15855171
[89,] 33 34 -0.10088338
[90,] 33 41 0.12001003
[91,] 33 43 -0.18284373
[92,] 33 46 -0.16394107
[93,] 33 49 0.15275365
[94,] 33 53 -0.14424536
[95,] 33 62 -0.18298613
[96,] 35 49 0.15671584
[97,] 36 49 -0.19092302
[98,] 37 49 0.12580630
[99,] 37 59 -0.10462770
[100,] 38 49 -0.12257773
[101,] 40 49 -0.09667345
[102,] 41 49 0.10453115
[103,] 42 49 -0.11113257
[104,] 43 49 -0.10493318
[105,] 48 49 0.18244989
[106,] 49 51 0.15013766
[107,] 49 52 -0.15366076
[108,] 49 54 0.11142246
[109,] 49 56 -0.13114785
[110,] 49 57 -0.17502184
[111,] 49 58 0.18643826
[112,] 49 59 -0.17610071
[113,] 49 60 0.11064330
[114,] 49 61 -0.13522543
```

nodeslist:

```
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

I have the necessary information in order to draw this network, how can i do that? if i try something like:

```
plot(g)
```

it only plots as an image on the dashboard, how can i draw like to make it interactive?

Comment: Did you try https://bwlewis.github.io/rthreejs/ ?

Comment: `rthreejs` seems not bad : in 3D  !!  :)

Comment: @Ream: Do you get some suitable interactive graph ? With my 2nd answer or `rthreejs` ? Or other ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other answer inspired from [R-bloggers : Network Graphs in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/07/network-graphs-in-r-2/) because after a the comments I've read than `igraph` is not supported by `plotly`.

Be careful I've not verified the logic of the network.

You need to run the part one and two to run the 3rd part about networkD3.

Some weight are negative: I'm not sure that is good thing for network libraries nor if they are well implemented for that.

```
flat_dataset <-"r  a b weight
[1,] 1 49 0.13920793
[2,] 2 19 -0.16105155
[3,] 2 29 -0.11896011
[4,] 2 49 0.10574541
[5,] 3 29 -0.13120939
[6,] 3 49 0.17390062
[7,] 4 10 -0.10381197
 snip snip snip
[113,] 49 60 0.11064330
[114,] 49 61 -0.13522543
"

data <-read.table(textConnection(flat_dataset),header=TRUE)
```

You have to change the datas by yours completed : the lines above was only to have datas to test it.

```
print(as_tibble(data))
# A tibble: 114 × 4
   r         a     b weight
   <chr> <int> <int>  <dbl>
 1 [1,]      1    49  0.139
 2 [2,]      2    19 -0.161
 3 [3,]      2    29 -0.119
 4 [4,]      2    49  0.106
 5 [5,]      3    29 -0.131
 6 [6,]      3    49  0.174
 7 [7,]      4    10 -0.104
 8 [8,]      5    33 -0.135
 9 [9,]      6    49  0.175
10 [10,]     7    19  0.187
# … with 104 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Below packages loaded. They have to be installed before.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph))
library(ggraph)
library(networkD3)
library(tidygraph)
```

### Part 1 igraph

Part `igraph` from the article but with your datas. <strike>The datas seem maybe incomplete : nearly all of the nodes are orphans</strike> . Without quantile filter they don't seem incomplete.

```
graph <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(data, directed = FALSE)
plot(graph)

# Warning message in v(graph):
# “Non-positive edge weight found, ignoring all weights during graph layout.”
```

[image: igraph plot 1]

```
data2 <- data[data$weight >= stats::quantile(data$weight, p = 0.98),,]
data2
```

If you want all datas you have to do below in place of above:

```
data2 <- data
```

The 1st graph but with quantile filter :

```
data2 %>%
    igraph::graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
    plot(layout = layout_with_graphopt)
```

[image: igraph plot 2]

The 1st graph without quantile filter: with `data2 <- data`:

[image: igraph plot 1 without quantile]

### Part 2 `tidygraph` and `ggraph`

```
nodes <- c(data$a, data$b) %>% 
    unique() %>%
    # tibble from tidyverse library
    tibble::tibble(label = .) %>%
    tibble::rowid_to_column("id")

# nodes
```

same with weight in the label and id:

```
nodes <- c(data$a, data$b, data$weight) %>% 
    unique()  %>%
    tibble::tibble(label = .) %>%
    tibble::rowid_to_column("id")
```

I suppose (maybe badly)  for `tidygraph::tbl_graph()`, that:

- `a` is `from`
- `b` is `to`
- `weight` is `N`

```
edges <- data2 %>%
    # join the example, but your network seems already made
    # dplyr::left_join(nodes, by = c("Person1"="label")) %>%
    # dplyr from tidyverse package
    dplyr::rename(N = "weight") %>%
    dplyr::rename(from = "a") %>%
    # join the example, but your network seems already made
    # dplyr::left_join(nodes, by = c("Person2"="label")) %>%
    dplyr::rename("to" = "b") %>%
    dplyr::select(from, to, N)



graph_tidy <- tidygraph::tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges, directed = FALSE)

graph_tidy
```

That gives  to me:

```
# A tbl_graph: 63 nodes and 3 edges
#
# An unrooted forest with 60 trees
#
# A tibble: 63 × 2
     id label
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
4     4     4
5     5     5
6     6     6
# … with 57 more rows
#
# A tibble: 3 × 3
   from    to     N
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     7    19 0.187
2    25    35 0.187
3    30    49 0.189
```

```
graph_tidy %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Centrality = tidygraph::centrality_authority()) %>%
    ggraph::ggraph(layout = "graphopt") + 
    ggraph::geom_node_point(aes(size=Centrality, colour = label), show.legend = FALSE) +
    ggraph::geom_edge_link(aes(width = N), alpha = 0.8, show.legend = FALSE) + 
    ggraph::scale_edge_width(range = c(0.2, 2)) +
    ggraph::geom_node_text(aes(label = label), repel = TRUE)
# Warning message:
# “Using the `size` aesthetic in this geom was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
# Please use `linewidth` in the `default_aes` field and elsewhere instead.”
# my comment: linewidth doesn't work there
```

[image: Tidygraph_and_GGraph1]

The same graph without quantile filter: with `data2 <- data` (at the beginning):

[image: without quantile]

With weight as part of id and label:

[image: With weight as part of id and label]

### Part 3 `networkD3`

```
edges <- edges %>%
        dplyr::mutate(from = from -1, to = to - 1) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(N = N / 200)

# edges
```

```
nodes <- nodes %>%
    dplyr::mutate(id=id-1) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(nodesize = igraph::authority.score(graph_tidy)$vector*150)

# nodes
```

```
networkD3::forceNetwork(Links = edges, 
             Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "from", 
             Target = "to", 
             NodeID = "label", 
             Group = "id", 
             opacity = 1,
             fontSize = 14,
             zoom = TRUE, 
             Value = "N", 
             Nodesize = "nodesize", 
             opacityNoHover = TRUE
)
# Warning message:
# “It looks like Source/Target is not zero-indexed. This is required in  JavaScript and so your plot may not render.”
# Nodes is a tbl_df. Converting to a plain data frame.
```

And I see an interactive network .

I can move and click on the points (but printscreened here).

[image: Network3D.jpg]

The same graph without quantile filter: with `data2 <- data` (at the beginning):

[image]

With weight as part of id and label (extract of the graph):

[image]

It's a [Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG):

```html
<div class="forceNetwork html-widget html-fill-item-overflow-hidden html-fill-item html-widget-static-bound" id="htmlwidget-380bfc22386ecfa1b181" style="width:960px;height:500px;">
    <svg width="960" height="500" pointer-events="all">
        <g class="zoom-layer">
            <g>
                <line class="link" style="stroke: rgb(102, 102, 102); opacity: 0.25; stroke-width: 0.00216273px;" x1="410.4125002318474" y1="235.5820858923744" x2="374.73641851106566" y2="252.4766163768353"></line>
...
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Links:

- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/networkD3/versions/0.4/topics/forceNetwork
- http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_networkD3.html
- http://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plotly` to transform your plot into interactive plot.

> `plotly::plotly_build`:
>
> Description :
>
> This generic function creates the list object sent to plotly.js for rendering. Using this function can be useful for overriding defaults provided by ggplotly/plot_ly or for debugging rendering errors.

> `Plotly` R Open Source Graphing Library
>
> Plotly's R graphing library makes interactive, publication-quality graphs.

```
plot_object<- plot(g)

plotly_object<-plotly::ggplotly(plot_object)

p<-plotly::plotly_build(plotly_objet)

p$elementId <- NULL

# display the interactive plot: 
p
```

Try without `p$elementId <- NULL` depending of  `plotly` version:

- [github.com/ropensci/plotly # 985: Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID; Shiny doesn't use them](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/985)

Edit:

`igraph` seems that doesn't work with ploty
:

- https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/496#issuecomment-990209544

Comment: I got the following error:

Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "network_plot"

Comment: I cannot help you without reproducible example (functions, examples of datas with `dput(mydata)`  :)

Comment: Try `plot_object<- g` because I don't at which level of graph lib you are, neither I don't know if your network is compatible with `plotly` if I cannot test.

Comment: here is the github link for the tool "SeqNet" which I'm trying to switch from being an igraph to visNetwork/plotly:

https://github.com/tgrimes/SeqNet

Comment: if you need more info tell me of a way to send you ui.R,server.R, global.R if you need it

Comment: `SeqNet` is too old for my 4.2.2  R version : "`install.packages("SeqNet")` : package ‘SeqNet’ is not available for this version of R". A good reprex is when the code is representative and short enough to be pasted on Stack Overflow.  `SeqNet` [seems based on igraph](https://github.com/tgrimes/SeqNet/blob/master/R/plotting.R#L19) and  [igraph seems that doesn't work with ploty](https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/496#issuecomment-990209544)

Comment: From https://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html "`plot.igraph` does simple **non-interactive** 2D plotting to R devices. "

Comment: `plotly` can make interactive `ggplot2` plots  (and maybe other non interactive libs like `ggplot2`), but this must be intended for.

Comment: Therefore you have to adapt your network datas from `SeqNet` to another graphic library than `igraph` to get an interactive graph.

Comment: [R-bloggers : Network Graphs in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/07/network-graphs-in-r-2/)

Comment: so Is what i did not enough to extract the necessary data for plotting? Like i took the nodes data from 1 module and put it in a list, took the edges data (contains weights) from the same module and put it in a list, do i need to do more? Or? I would love some guidance regarding this

Comment: I write an other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer really simpler and more concise. Inspired from this article:

- "Katya Ognyanova, June 26th, 2023: Static and dynamic network visualization with R", https://kateto.net/network-visualization, part "6.2 Interactive JS visualization with visNetwork", (and lot of useful informations).

#### Datas from your message

```
flat_dataset <-"r  a b weight
[1,] 1 49 0.13920793
[2,] 2 19 -0.16105155
[3,] 2 29 -0.11896011
[4,] 2 49 0.10574541
[5,] 3 29 -0.13120939
[6,] 3 49 0.17390062
[7,] 4 10 -0.10381197
[8,] 5 33 -0.13458892
[9,] 6 49 0.17523747
[10,] 7 19 0.18709664
[11,] 8 49 -0.10200550
[12,] 9 10 -0.16075495
[13,] 9 49 0.12597721
[14,] 10 11 0.12419045
[15,] 10 18 0.16554176
[16,] 10 23 0.12257816
[17,] 10 24 0.17552470
[18,] 10 25 -0.18485569
[19,] 10 28 -0.18851376
[20,] 10 29 -0.17173121
[21,] 10 32 0.14237557
[22,] 10 33 -0.15823895
[23,] 10 34 0.12432978
[24,] 10 35 -0.16700940
[25,] 10 37 0.17640358
[26,] 10 43 -0.10804470
[27,] 10 44 0.16079198
[28,] 10 45 -0.13074089
[29,] 10 47 -0.14941716
[30,] 10 48 0.17069436
[31,] 10 49 -0.14465740
[32,] 10 50 -0.16713456
[33,] 10 51 -0.12124140
[34,] 10 53 0.09832430
[35,] 10 55 -0.16044640
[36,] 10 62 0.15869645
[37,] 10 63 0.11175158
[38,] 12 49 -0.19139133
[39,] 13 29 0.14681721
[40,] 13 49 0.13493487
[41,] 14 33 -0.13364581
[42,] 15 19 0.10663959
[43,] 15 49 -0.11776805
[44,] 16 49 -0.17496817
[45,] 17 49 0.13980787
[46,] 19 24 0.16020803
[47,] 19 25 -0.12007548
[48,] 19 26 0.13061010
[49,] 19 30 0.18347088
[50,] 19 32 0.17066294
[51,] 19 33 -0.16345597
[52,] 19 37 0.12446608
[53,] 19 46 0.13531279
[54,] 19 49 0.10353267
[55,] 19 52 -0.12596833
[56,] 19 63 0.11966468
[57,] 20 49 -0.13018907
[58,] 21 33 -0.10584546
[59,] 21 49 -0.16366432
[60,] 22 29 -0.12769928
[61,] 24 29 0.09683651
[62,] 24 49 -0.17398705
[63,] 25 30 -0.18163093
[64,] 25 34 0.13093457
[65,] 25 35 0.18703481
[66,] 25 41 0.11050505
[67,] 25 44 -0.09962966
[68,] 25 47 0.18286832
[69,] 26 29 0.14178880
[70,] 26 33 -0.10631235
[71,] 27 37 -0.14746540
[72,] 28 33 0.09948649
[73,] 29 30 0.13360557
[74,] 29 31 -0.16245800
[75,] 29 32 -0.16785796
[76,] 29 33 -0.15289176
[77,] 29 39 -0.17283268
[78,] 29 43 0.10077533
[79,] 29 49 -0.13001863
[80,] 29 50 -0.11811612
[81,] 29 51 -0.17453024
[82,] 29 53 -0.12620716
[83,] 29 59 -0.16878030
[84,] 29 63 0.11351594
[85,] 30 37 0.15382473
[86,] 30 49 0.18885891
[87,] 31 49 0.16179096
[88,] 32 49 0.15855171
[89,] 33 34 -0.10088338
[90,] 33 41 0.12001003
[91,] 33 43 -0.18284373
[92,] 33 46 -0.16394107
[93,] 33 49 0.15275365
[94,] 33 53 -0.14424536
[95,] 33 62 -0.18298613
[96,] 35 49 0.15671584
[97,] 36 49 -0.19092302
[98,] 37 49 0.12580630
[99,] 37 59 -0.10462770
[100,] 38 49 -0.12257773
[101,] 40 49 -0.09667345
[102,] 41 49 0.10453115
[103,] 42 49 -0.11113257
[104,] 43 49 -0.10493318
[105,] 48 49 0.18244989
[106,] 49 51 0.15013766
[107,] 49 52 -0.15366076
[108,] 49 54 0.11142246
[109,] 49 56 -0.13114785
[110,] 49 57 -0.17502184
[111,] 49 58 0.18643826
[112,] 49 59 -0.17610071
[113,] 49 60 0.11064330
[114,] 49 61 -0.13522543
"
```

#### Data transformation

```
library(utils) # for utils::read.table()
library(tidyverse) # for dplyr::mutate and dplyr::transmute()
library(visNetwork) # for visNetwork::visNetwork()


data <-utils::read.table(base::textConnection(flat_dataset),header=TRUE)

edgesList<-data %>% dplyr::transmute(from=a,to=b, label=as.character(weight))

nodeslist<-data %>% dplyr::transmute(id=a) %>% unique(.)
```

#### Interactive JS visualization with visNetwork

```
visNetwork::visNetwork(
  nodes=nodeslist,
  edges=edgesList,
  width="100%",
  height="600px"
)
```

There it's a printscreen but it's interactive when you execute it.

[image]

Extract of the documentation:

> visNetwork {visNetwork}   R Documentation
> Network visualization
>
> Description
>
> Network visualization using vis.js library. For full documentation, have a look at visDocumentation.
>
> Usage
>
> visNetwork(
> nodes = NULL,
> edges = NULL,
> dot = NULL,
> gephi = NULL,
> width = NULL,
> height = NULL,
> main = NULL,
> submain = NULL,
> footer = NULL,
> background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
> ...
> )
>
> Arguments
>
> nodes : data.frame or a list with nodes informations. Needed at least column "id". See visNodes
>
> - "id" : id of the node, needed in edges information
> - "label" : label of the node
> - "group" : group of the node. Groups can be configure with visGroups
> - "value" : size of the node
> - "title" : tooltip of the node
> - ...
>
> edges : data.frame or a list with edges informations. Needed at least columns "from" and "to". See visEdges
>
> - "from" : node id of begin of the edge
> - "to" : node id of end of the edge
> - "label" : label of the edge
> - "value" : size of the node
> - "title" : tooltip of the node
> - ...